# How do I find an existing object in my database?

Tags: django

I have a form which accepts data from a user and is posted with ajax. This form is used to schedule calendar events.

When the user adds an event I want to see if one with the same details exists.

The event model has a calendar associated with it: like this

```
class EventModel(models.Model):
    calendar = models.ForeignKey(CalenderModel, blank=True, null=True, related_name="plans")
    event_details = models.IntegerField()
```

Here is what my event looks like when it is created in the view:

```
event = EventModel(calendar=calendar, event_details =request.Post['event_details'])
event.save()
```

When the user tries to modify the existing event or tries to add the event again, I would like to be able to find the event he/she is talking about.

How would I do this without being specific? I'd like something like

```
event = EventModel.objects.get(calendar=calendar).filter(event_details = event_details)
```

This should return the one event with the same details

but it is not finding it...

Is there a better way to make this happen?

Comment: First, a little off-topic, you can simplify your request like this: `EventModel.objects.get(calendar=calendar, event_details=event_details)`

Comment: Does that automatically get the data from request?

Answer (score 0):

Just try like that:

```
event, created = EventModel.objects.get_or_create(calendar=calendar, event_details = event_details)
```

And created is a Boolean that indicates whether the event was created now, ie. nothing like that was in the DB yet, or if it has just retrieved an existing on.e

Answer (score 0):

You can not call of `filter` method after then you called `get` method, becouse `get` method return one instance of model or exception, not `queryset`. Try this:

```
try:
    event = EventModel.objects.get(calendar=calendar, event_details=event_details)
except EventModel.DoesNotExist:
    # create here if need
except EventModel.MultipleObjectsReturned:
    # do something if you have two or more values with this data
```